# Where is Internet Options now that Internet Explorer is gone?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, compatibility, control-panel

Internet Explorer retired and is no longer supported. Microsoft has pushed updates that disable access to Internet Explorer. Problem is that some applications still use a WebView component which e.g. has its default fonts governed by the internet options that used to be available from within Internet Explorer.

How do you access the internet options now that Internet Explorer is gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these options from the control panel (in Windows 10, it is Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Options) or from within Edge:

- Go to edge://settings/defaultBrowser
- Set "Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode (IE mode)" to "Allow" and restart the browser
- Return to the above page and select "Internet Options"

You can also click Start => Run... => type `inetcpl.cpl`

Comment: @John Not sure what you're trying to say. The fact that it isn't a new thing shouldn't matter. (I hit it for the first time today.)